# Import CSV to Database Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, csv, upload

I m ssing Laravel 5.3
Trying to upload Csv file to database. Csv titles and database fields are the same. File is uploaded to server with no problem but i cant get the data into Database. what am i doing wrong? It says CSV imported successfully but nothing in the database. thanks

```
function postImport( Request $request)
{

    if(!is_null($request->file('fileimport')))
    {
        $file =     $request->file('fileimport');
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $uploadSuccess = $file->move('./uploads/' , $filename );
        if( $uploadSuccess ) {
            $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('./uploads/'.$filename));
            $table = $this->info['config']['grid'];
            $fields = array();
            foreach($table as $f )
            {
                $fields[] = $f['field'];
            }
            //print_r($fields);
            foreach($csv as $row) {
                $data = array();
                foreach($fields as $key=>$val)
                {
                    if($key != 0 )
                        $data[$val] = (isset($row[$key]) ? $row[$key] : '' ) ;  
                }
                //print_r($data);
                //echo $row[0];
                $this->model->insertRow($data ,$row[0]);    

            }

            return response()->json(array('status'  => 'success','message'=>'Csv Imported Successfully !'));              
        } else {
            return response()->json(array('status'  => 'error','message'=>'Upload Failed!'));   
        }
    } else {            
        return response()->json(array('status'  => 'error','message'=>'Please select file to Upload!'));
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Using `array_push` to populate `fields` array

```
function postImport( Request $request)
    {

        if(!is_null($request->file('fileimport')))
        {
            $file =     $request->file('fileimport');
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $uploadSuccess = $file->move('./uploads/' , $filename );
            if( $uploadSuccess ) {
                $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('./uploads/'.$filename));
                $table = $this->info['config']['grid'];
                $fields = array();
                foreach($table as $f )
                {
                  array_push($fields,$f['field']);
                }
                //print_r($fields);
                foreach($csv as $row) {
                    $data = array();
                    foreach($fields as $key=>$val)
                    {
                        if($key != 0 )
                            $data[$val] = (isset($row[$key]) ? $row[$key] : '' ) ;  
                    }
                    //print_r($data);
                    //echo $row[0];
                    $this->model->insertRow($data ,$row[0]);    

                }

                return response()->json(array('status'  => 'success','message'=>'Csv Imported Successfully !'));              
            } else {
                return response()->json(array('status'  => 'error','message'=>'Upload Failed!'));   
            }
        } else {            
            return response()->json(array('status'  => 'error','message'=>'Please select file to Upload!'));
        }   

    }
```

Comment: Still Same. File uploaded but nothing at the database :(